# iCloud is turned off but settings still shows data being uploaded

Tags: ios, icloud

Steps to reproduce:
Launch the application
Go to device settings -> iCloud -> Storage & Backup -> Manage Storage -> Device name
Look for Disney Store within the application list and observe the size for the app

Observed Results: Application uploads data to iCloud.
Expected results: Application should not upload any data to iCloud if it is not intended to support it.

Comment: What is your question? Is this happening with an app that you wrote? What does the Disney app have to do with it?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, this is the Disney Stores application were working on. The question really is why does the application indicate that data is being uploaded when we have our iCloud setting off and we are not storing any data locally. Except for some keychain data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see on that screen is how much space is needed to back up the application's data to iCloud. You'll notice before you tap on the device that it's in a section of the table labeled "BACKUPS", and that the app itself appears under "Next Backup Size".

Backing up to iCloud has nothing at all to do with whether your app supports or uses iCloud. It includes whatever data is needed to restore your app to its current state if the user needs to restore their device from a backup.

The only control you have over this is

- The obvious approach of limiting the amount of data you create
- Files can be marked as excluded from backups using `NSURL` to set the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` property.

I don't think keychain data can be specifically excluded.